# Не работает автоматическая выгрузка товаров на сайт из 1с(Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, 1с, wordpress-плагины

Проблема с плагином WooCommerce and 1C:Enterprise/1С:Предприятие Data Exchange.

```
Команды
/wc1c/exchange
/?wc1c=exchange
```

Не работают. Ошибка `Error: No type.`
А при ручной выгрузке командой

```
/?wc1c=exchange?type=catalog&mode=import&filename=import.xml
/wc1c/exchange/?type=catalog&mode=import&filename=offers.xml
```

все работает, но это ручной режим.
При проверке соединения с сайтом в 1с пишет, что соединение установлено.

```
Сайт работает через http.
```

Почему не работает автоматическая выгрузка товаров на сайт из 1с?

Comment: Что-то не так настроили. Приведённые в вопросе команды работают, использовал.

Comment: @KAGG Design, Ну вопрос, где не так настроено, со стороны сайта или 1с?

Comment: @KAGG Design, ведь в ручном режиме все работает.

Comment: Я бы помнил, сразу бы написал ответ. Давно использовал, с год назад, всё работало и в автоматическом режиме.

Comment: Попробуй добавить правило в .htaccess `RewriteRule . - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`